Duplication of mathematical notations while auto-compiling of latex code in overleaf
For a latex code which compiles fine and works well for long time, sometimes, out of nowhere, it gives the following error while typing in overleaf. The error message is shown between the next two lines

not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.368 given by ⊕
                  d|N/rSnew2k(r)|Wd.\oplus_{d\vert N/r}\; S_{2k}^{new}(r)\ve...
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter


The problem is that at this time, my source code is automatically geting changed from
$\oplus_{d\vert N/r}\; S_{2k}^{new}(r)\vert W_d$.

to
⊕d|N/rSnew2k(r)|Wd.\oplus_{d\vert N/r}\; S_{2k}^{new}(r)\vert W_d.


Here, ⊕d|N/rSnew2k(r)|Wd replaces the dollar $ symbols covering \oplus_{d\vert N/r}\; S_{2k}^{new}(r)\vert W_d. I feel that I may have done some error in mynewcommands. Can someone explain it to me?
These are the new commands that I have created for myself.
\newcommand{\A}{{\mathscr A}}

\newcommand{\C}{{\mathbb C}}

\newcommand{\Z}{{\mathbb Z}}

\newcommand{\HP}{{\mathbb H}}

\newcommand{\D}{{\mathscr D}}

\newcommand{\F}{{\mathscr F}}

\newcommand{\Oh}{{\mathcal O}}

\newcommand{\newspace}[1]{S_{2k}^{new}($#1$)}

\newcommand{\legendre}[2]{\left( \frac{#1}{#2} \right) }

\newcommand{\inner}[2]{\langle #1, #2 \rangle}

\newcommand{\normsq}[1]{\| #1 \|^2}

Any way to fix this?

These unicode characters automatically gets appended in front of my source code and replaces dollar symbol by the unicode version of my mathematical notation. I have not declared by myself. At least this is what I understand

These are the errors: Unicode character ≤ (U+2264) not set up for use with LaTeX, Unicode character ℓ (U+2113) not set up for use with LaTeX.

Is the dollar symbol here an error? \newcommand{\newspace}[1]{S_{2k}^{new}($#1$)}

yes they are an error also new is wrong, it should be \mathrm{new}

I am working on a code that came from someone else and I don't know what is the trigger for this unicode appending in source code. I only know latex on a need-to-know basis and zero in terminologies like unicode etc. Can I fix the errors that you pointed out and wait it out to see if it is occurring again? After that, may be if you could allow me to get back to you here within a day? (It is late night here)

I am using the customised newcommand newspace in the following way: ....basis for the eigenclass generated by $\newspace{r}$.... The dollar symbols used here along with the dollars in the definition of newcommand as given above could have been the cause for duplication, you believe?

Please, is there any chance you run a browser extension like TeX All The Things or similar? If so, can you try disabling it? It molests the files in the Overleaf editor, causing issues like this.

Oh no I haven't. However after previous modifications (removing dollar symbol in newcommand), this issue hasn't happened yet.
